# Exercise on Spectrum of Commutative Elements in a Banach Algebra

Tags: spectral-theory, banach-algebras, spectral-radius

> Given an element $A$ of a Banach algebra $V$ and $\epsilon > 0$, prove that if $0 \in \textrm{sp}(A)$, then there is $\delta > 0$ such that if $B \in V$ commutes with $A$ and $||A-B|| < \delta$, then there is a $\lambda$ in $\textrm{sp}(B)$ with $|\lambda | < \epsilon$.

**My Attempt**

My goal was to prove that by making $\delta$ small enough, we can guarantee $r(B)$ (spectral radius of $B$) to be less than $\epsilon$, and then use the fact that the spectrum is non-empty to prove the existence of such a $\lambda$.

Since $A$ and $B$ commutes, then $B-A$ and $A$ commutes, so we have:
$$r(B) = r(B-A+A) \leq r(B-A) + r(A) \leq ||B-A|| + r(A).$$
I am not sure how to proceed from here. I do not think this approach will work since I think the RHS of the above expression will not always be less than $\epsilon$ since $r(A)$ can be anything. However, I cannot think of any other approaches to take.

Could someone give a hint on how to approach this question?

Comment: Hint:  consider the commutative Banach algebra generated by $A$ and $B$ and use the fact that the spectrum of an element $x$ in a commutative Banach algebra is the set of all $\phi(x)$, where $\phi$ ranges in the set of all complex homomorphisms on your algebra.

Comment: @Ruy Thanks for the hint! I was not aware of that fact before. I can see the result easily follows by using continuity of homomorphisms.

Comment: Here is the proof: given a complex homomorphism $f$, one has that $$f(x-f(x)1)=0,$$ so $x-f(x)$ cannot be invertible (otherwise its image under $f$ would be an invertible complex number), so $f(x)\in\sigma(x)$.  Conversely, if $a \in\sigma(x)$, then $A\cdot (x-a )$ is a proper ideal.  By Zorn it is contained in a maximal ideal $J$, so $A/J$ is a field (every element is invertible).  But Gelfand-Mazur then implies that $A/J$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$.  The quotient map $\pi :A\to A/J=\mathbb C$ is then a complex homomorphism.  Since $\pi (x-a )=0$, it follows that $\pi (x)=a $.

Comment: @Ruy actually, I have 1 question. Suppose the commutative Banach algebra generated is $W$. Then I can prove there is a such a $\lambda$ in $\textrm{sp}_W(B)$ but then how can I prove it is in $\textrm{sp}_V(B)$ since $\textrm{sp}_V(B) \subseteq \textrm{sp}_W(B)$?

Comment: You do have a point there.  Let me think about it...

Comment: OK, I was wrong to choose the algebra generated by $A$ and $B$.  Instead, given any Banach algebra $V$, and a
commutative subalgebra $W$ (e.g. the algebra generated by $A$ and $B$), I claim that there exists another commutative
subalgebra $W'$, containing $W$, such that for any element $a$ in $W$, one has that $a$ is invertible relative to $W'$
iff $a$ is invertible relative to $V$ and, in particular, $$ \text{sp}_{W'}(a)=\text{sp}_{V}(a).  $$  Replacing $W$ by $W'$ inthe previous argument would solve the problem, do you agree?

Comment: @Ruy Right that makes sense. In choosing $W'$, is it correct to say that letting $W'$ be the algebra generated by all elements which are commutative with $A$ and $B$ will work? Since if $A-\lambda I$ is invertible, then its inverse is commutative with $A$ and hence will be in $W'$. Thus $\textrm{sp}_V(B) = \textrm{sp}_{W'}(B).

Comment: The trouble is that the commutant is not necessarily commutative.  But of course you got pretty close!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma**.  Given a unital Banach algebra $V$, and a
commutative subalgebra $W$,  there exists another commutative
subalgebra $W_1$, containing $W$, such that for any element $a$ in $W_1$, one has that $a$ is invertible relative to $W_1$
iff $a$ is invertible relative to $V$.   In particular, $$ \text{sp}_{V}(a)=\text{sp}_{W_1}(a),  $$
for every $a$ in $W_1$.

*Proof*. For every subset $S\subseteq V$, define the *commutant* of $S$ by
$$
  S'=\{a\in  V: as=sa: \text{ for all } s\in S\}.
  $$
It is
easy to see that

(1) $S'$ is always a unital subalgebra,

(2) $S$ is commutative iff $S\subseteq S'$,

(3) if $S\subseteq T$ then $S'\supseteq T'$.

(4) if $a\in S'$, and $a$ is invertible,  then $a^{-1}\in S'$.

Now, given $W$ as in the statement, we claim that  $W_1:= W''$ (that is, the commutant of the commutant of $W$) satisfies all of the required conditions.

First  observe that $W\subseteq W''$ by the following very trivial (if clumsy) reason:  every element of $W$ commutes with
everything that commutes with the elements of $W$.

Since $W$ is commutative, we deduce from (2) that  $W\subseteq W'$.  Using
(3) we get $W'\supseteq W''$, and   using (3) again we get $W''\subseteq W'''$. So the converse part of (2) implies that $W''$ is commutative.

Finally the last condition in the statement regarding invertible elements follows immediately from (4). QED

Back to the original question,  consider the commutative Banach algebra $W$ generated by $A$  and $B$,  and let $W_1$ be
as in the Lemma.  Then, for every element $a$ in $W_1$, we have that
$$
  \text{sp}_{V}(a)=\text{sp}_{W_1}(a) = \{\phi(a): \phi\in \text{Hom}(W_1, \mathbb C)\},
  $$
so the end result follows easily by the continuity of complex homomorphisms.